# Linux bootup (Ctrl + Scroll Lock) key combination

Tags: linux, boot, keyboard-shortcuts

If i press Ctrl + Scroll Lock (during bootup) some information will be shown, I want to know about this information.

[image: output sample]

And also how to check it page by page?
I used (Shift+Page up) but the history wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could access some information via `dmesg` command. You could see all kernel log for freshly started system.

Comment: There is no information about these messages in dmesg, i want to know what's this? this is somewhat like top output, something about processes

Answer (score 0):

In the file, `linux-keys-bare.inc` (retrieved from `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-keys-bare.inc` on my machine) it has keycode 70 set to this:

```
plain   keycode  70 = Scroll_Lock
shift   keycode  70 = Show_Memory
control keycode  70 = Show_State
alt     keycode  70 = Show_Registers
```

Keycode 70 is the Scroll Lock key:
[image: Scancode diagram of the UK Keyboard, showing that Scroll Lock has the keycode of hex 46]
[Retrieved from kbdlayout.info/KBDUK](https://kbdlayout.info/KBDUK/scancodes+text?arrangement=ISO105)

Hex 46 -> 70

so by pressing Control + Scroll Lock, you are telling the linux kernel to "show state", you could also try Shift + Scroll Lock to "show memory" and Alt + Scroll Lock to "show registers"

On further inspection, it appears that "show state" triggers the scheduler to print out information about processes (ie. task name, wait time, sch delay and run time)

See this source file for more information [torvalds/linux/tools/perf/builtin-sched.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8fa590bf344816c925810331eea8387627bbeb40/tools/perf/builtin-sched.c)

I couldn't find much information about "show memory" and "show registers" - there's probably some reference to them in the Linux kernel, I just haven't been able to find it